# Laptop AC Adapter using a higher Amp or Watt rated and effects

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a laptop AC Adapter that has a power specification of 19v 3.42A  65watt and the laptop power requirements are 60 watt. What are the likely effects of using a higher rated AC adapter, ie 19V 4.74A 90watt . My understanding is that the laptop cannot draw more current than required and even though the 4.74A AC adapter has a higher capacity, it would not effect the laptop as the laptop would only draw 3.16A as max. Can this be confirmed? Also is it physically possible for a laptop to draw more power than its specification ie can my 60 watt Laptop suddenly decide to draw 90 watts through its system and cause damage? Is there any possibility of damage to the laptop by using a higher AMP rated (same voltage) AC Adapter?